# Does the postgres Database contains/maintain the details of remote access like ip addresses?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

We have the pg_hba.conf entries for the remote access in PostgreSQL. Does PostgreSQL stores those data in the database itself?

Comment: Stores which data? The access control definition is only stored in pg_hba.conf

Comment: like ip address of the remote host.

Comment: look into the view `pg_stat_activity` that information is available in `client_addr` and `client_hostname`